# Example of a kinesthetic "quasimode" on mobile web app?

Tags: interaction-design, mobile-web

I would like to specify a function to zoom into an image displayed on a handset UI for industrial use. This is in an environment where users are often in situations where fine motor control is difficult. The nature of the application also means we must avoid mode errors as much as possible and single-handed operation is desired.

The interaction I would like is a kinesthetic "quasimode" (as per Jef Raskin 'The humane interface' 7, p. 55):

- The operator would tap and hold on the thumbnail of the image, which
  would then immediately increase to, say, double size until the hold is released, reverting back
  to thumbnail size again.
- The user does not need to pan, move or otherwise manipulate the image
  beyond making it larger. The fact that the finger would obscure part of the image during the qasimode is I don't think much of a problem.

Does anyone have any examples of a similar tap/hold quasimode (preferably with hints at how to implement it) in a mobile web context? The handset uses Android Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this with `mousedown/mouseup` events, and their touch equivalents, `touchstart/touchend`.

```
image.addEventListener('touchstart', () => {
  image.classList.add('zoomed')
  document.addEventListener('touchend', () => image.classList.remove('zoomed'), { once: true })
})
```

Here, we're adding an event listener to the image for `touchstart` events. When the event is fired, the class `zoomed` is added to the image, which gives it a style with `transform: scale(2)`.

We then add another listener to the `document` itself, to listen for the `touchend` event - and remove the `zoomed` class. Importantly, this is added with the `once: true` option, so when it receives the `touchend` event, it removes itself from `document`.

The reason we add the second listener to the `document` (rather than the `image`), is that if the cursor is dragged outside of the image while touched/down, the `touchend` event won't be fired on the `image`.

Adding `draggable="false"` to the `img` element will prevent the image being dragged around with the cursor.

Example parts:

```
<img class="zoomable-image" src="http://my-image-url" width="128" draggable="false">
```

```
.zoomable-image {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.zoomable-image.zoomed {
  transform: scale(2)
}
```

```
document.querySelectorAll('.zoomable-image').forEach(image => {
  image.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
    image.classList.add('zoomed')
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => image.classList.remove('zoomed'), { once: true })
  })

  image.addEventListener('touchstart', () => {
    image.classList.add('zoomed')
    document.addEventListener('touchend', () => image.classList.remove('zoomed'), { once: true })
  })
})
```